# Alfresco Community Module Loader problems

Tags: sugarcrm

The problem is the Module Loader window. Action and Enable/Disable buttons don't appear.

- SugarCRM Community 6.5.13
- CentOS 6.6

-- https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bJJ8.png

I need to enable modules. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens in a lot of Sugar instances with modules were installed approximately "a while ago." The buttons seem to disappear after a some amount of time or if the package files were removed from the underlying system. Module Loader packages can also be made with the intention of not ever removing them.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I see 4 modules but which are you trying to remove and why? You may find it's easier to manually remove the changes depending on the package.

Comment: I need to change the language to Spanish (first module).

Comment: And enable the module for Mailchimp.